# Memory increase (leaks) in application for iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sqlite, memory-leaks

I've got a memory problem when my code is running.
My device's RAM is constantly increasing, without ever decreasing. I don't understand why.

For your information, I've got a part in my code which loops about 7000 times. (I already tried spliting this loop into several smaller ones, with no effect)
During this loop, I parse an XML file, then add some of the parsed informations in a sqlite database.
In order to kill my objects, I used the following block : "@autoreleasepool". It limits the RAM usage, but it's not sufficient to make the memory decrease.

The problem here is not my 7000 iterations ; they work just fine. But if I later try to iterate some more, then memory gets saturated and iOS kills my app. I need more informations to understand what's wrong with my code.

Here is the code part I used :

```
-(void)MultiInsertFamille:(NSArray *)familles
{
NSMutableArray *produits = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *famillesRetry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;
sqlite3 *bdd;

NSString *database = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mybdd.sqlite"];
if (sqlite3_open([database UTF8String], &bdd) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_exec(bdd, "BEGIN", 0, 0, 0);
    const char *sqlstatement="insert into Famille values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(bdd,sqlstatement , -1, &stmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        int hasError= 0;
        for(NSString *path in familles)
        {
            @autoreleasepool
            {
                XMLParserFamille *fa = [[XMLParserFamille alloc] initXMLParserFamille:path parseError:nil];
                for (ProduitData *p in fa.famille.Produits.Produit)
                {
                    [produits addObject:p];
                }
                FamilleData *fam = [fa.famille retain];
                [fa release];

                if (fam.champ_Recherche)
                    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [fam.champ_Recherche cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                else
                    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "NULL", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                NSString *pathImTh = @"";
                for (Attribut *att in fam.Attributs)
                {
                    if ([att.name isEqualToString:@"ProductThumbnail"])
                    {
                        pathImTh = att.value;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (![pathImTh isEqualToString:@""])
                    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [pathImTh cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                else
                    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, "NULL", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                if (fam.nom)
                    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [fam.nom cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                else
                    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, "NULL", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                if (fam.ordre)
                    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 4, [fam.ordre intValue]);
                else
                    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 4, 0);

                if (fam.uid)
                    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 5, [fam.uid cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                else
                    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 5, "NULL", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                if (fam.uid_Categorie)
                    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 6, [fam.uid_Categorie cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                else
                    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 6, "NULL", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                if (fam.xmlErrone)
                    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 7, [fam.xmlErrone intValue]);
                else
                    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 7, 0);

                if(sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    NSLog(@"OK FAMILLE");
                }
                else
                {
                    [famillesRetry addObject:fam.uid];
                    NSLog(@"sqlite3_step error famille: '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(bdd));
                    hasError= 1;
                }
                [fam release];
                sqlite3_reset(stmt);
            }
        }
        if( hasError == 0 ) {
            sqlite3_exec(bdd, "COMMIT", 0, 0, 0);
        }
        else {
            sqlite3_exec(bdd, "ROLLBACK", 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
sqlite3_close(bdd);
if (famillesRetry.count > 0)
    [self retryFamille:famillesRetry familleToInsert:familles];
[famillesRetry release];
[self MultiInsertProduit:produits];
[produits release];
}
```

Thanks in advance for your consideration.

Comment: Try using Xcode's Product->Profile menu option and select "Allocations" as the type of view to create.  That will let you see what kinds of objects and memory blocks are created and also let you see the sequence of events that retain and release them.

Comment: Have you run this through the static analyzer ("Product" - "Analyze" or shift+command+B)? This finds many manual memory management issues. Also use [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH11-SW4) to find the source of the leak.

Comment: You do not autorelease anything. So what is the point in using an @autoreleasepool block?

Comment: I used Analyze all the time for primary check off leaks and they haven't problems with this type of leaks in my code.

Comment: You have right Hermann this is with a previous version but now that just not really useful

Comment: Unlikely to be the issue, but I'd be inclined to `sqlite3_finalize` before `sqlite3_exec` of the commit/rollback. I assume sqlite can handle the intervening `sqlite3_exec`, but discretion is the better part of valour. Theoretically, I'd also suggest checking the `dealloc` of `XMLParserFamille`, `ProduitData`, `FamilleData`, `Attribut`, etc., but really the various leaks tools in Instruments should tell you precisely what sort of items are consuming your memory, which is a far more prudent and efficient way of tracking down the problem. Have you run it through Instruments yet?

Comment: Finally my error is in XML parse and other object class, i have some object that not dealloc (not detect with Analyze but detected with instruments leak). Thanks at all for your help specially Rob.